# Select files similar to Google Drive

Tags: user-interface, google-drive-api

How can I make a UI where selecting of files can be done similar to Google Drive's mobile app, but in a website?

Here's a screenshot of what I want to know.
[image]

I want the check icon, bottom menu bar (see how they are stacked one below the other) everything like this.
What should I learn/know to implement this? (like frameworks, libraries, etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this would be your own implementation. But if you are trying to create a web application using Drive API you can follow the github by [pinoyyid](https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive) and documentation of Google for [Drive REST API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). This could help you start your application. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it would be my own implementation. But I just wanted to know what should I know (any libraries, frameworks, etc.) to implement this.